# Typo on "Access to moderator tools" page

Tags: bug, spelling

Just above the "Can I see all flags?" heading, it says "Every of your actions counts in keeping the quality of the site."

Should read "Every *one* of your actions counts in keeping the quality of the site." or "Every action counts in keeping the quality of the site."

Almsot forgot a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: +1 _Melancholy_ is a misnomer. Consider revising.

Comment: I actually didn't know that. I try keep up on etymology, but the etymology of programming languages is more useful for my everyday life.

Comment: @nickhar: [citation needed]? =)

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a spelling mistake but instead of the suggestions from OP, I'd think that the following is more suitable and to the point:

> All of your actions count towards maintaining the quality of the site.

The quality is *maintained*, as far as I have read; and not *kept*.

Comment: That does sound better